# trying to pass data using Link in react but not working

Tags: reactjs

I am new to coding
I am trying to pass data from one component to another using props and passing data through Link but it is not working , as i am receiving state: undefined in the console.log

i m not able to figure out the mistake or error, please help me out

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../components/show.css';
import image from '../images/youtube_img2.png';


const ShowCard = (props) => {
const view = props.view;
// location = {
//   pathname: `/view/${sh._id}`,
//   obj: sh
// }
    return(
    <div className="video">
      <div className="video__thumbnail">
        <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/PpXUTUXU7Qc/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <Link 
      to=  {{ pathname: `/view/${view._id}`, 
          state: view
      }}
       >
      <div className="video__details">
        <div className="author">
          <img src={image} alt="Youtube ICOn" />
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          <h3>
            {view.title}
          </h3>
          <span>{view.year}</span>
          <span>{view.description}</span>
          <span>{view.trailer}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Link>
      <span className = "dp flex justify-content-end">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick= {() => props.delShow(view._id)}>Delete</button>
      </span>
      {/* <Link 
      to=  {{ pathname: `/edit`, state: {view:props.view}}}
       > */}
      <span className = "dp flex justify-content-start">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick= {() => props.delShow(view._id)}>Edit</button>
      </span>
      {/* </Link> */}
    </div>
    );

}

export default ShowCard;
```

here is the details page code

```
import React from 'react';
import '../components/details.css';

const ShowDetails = (props) => {
console.log(props)
return (
<div className="container-fulid">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="video">
          <iframe src={`http://www.youtube.com/embed/6Q9bxokO-5Y`}
          width="1500" height="615" frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen title= "dcdc"></iframe>
      </div>
    <div className="row">
      <h1>cddc</h1>
      <div className="text">
      <p>cdcd</p>
      <p>cddcd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 );
};

export default ShowDetails;
```

Comment: I cannot see where are you using the ShowDetails in your ShowCard

Comment: What is the React-Router version?

Comment: "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using react router dom v5.

The way you are passing state to link seems fine to me, now lets come to what can go wrong here :)

1. How to access that state in the respective component.

   Use useLocation hook

   **const { state } = useLocation;** (hooks can only be used in custom hooks and
   react components only)
2. If from first approach you still get it undefined:

   a. Try to check the value you are passing as state to link, whether its
   undefined or not.

   b. Check if you are using the first approach correctly or not.